# module.parent = null

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть файл 'server.js'

```
var user = require("./dir");

function run() {
    var vasya = new user.User("Вася");
    var petya = new user.User("Петя");

    vasya.hello(petya);
}
console.log(module.parent); //выводит Null но подключен в файле app
if (module.parent) {
    exports.run = run;
    console.log("Module required");
} else {
    run();
}
```

И 'app.js'

```
var server = require("./server");
```

Почему даже при том что через app.js подключили модуль server module.parent все равно выводит null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все модули кешируются и исполняются один раз.